# How properly design angularjs tabular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Single page application consists of tabs, which are created initially or during work.
Users should be able to open and close new tabs, switch between them back and forth, without changing affecting states of nested widgets.
Tabs contain alot of views, including various inputs and datasets rendered in grids.

If I understand correctly, ng-route and ui-route replace all content ng-view/ui-view, they cannot preserve complicated states and cannot be used to implement such tabs.

The way I see with tabs is bootstrap-style with tabset/tab directives or manually with ng-show/ng-hide.

## 1

If I do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsCtrl as ctrl">
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in ctrl.tabs>something</tab> 
</tabset>
</div>
```

How to make it not to rerender all the tabs when adding/removing them from ctrl.tabs?
Does using tabs.push/tabs.splice guarantee this?

## 2

To make tabs opening available anywhere in app, it should probably be a service. 
But to render them it should be controller.
I come up with such design:

```
.service('TabService', function() {
    this.tabs = []; /* list of all application tabs */
    this.openTab = function() { ... };
    this.closeTab = function() { ... };
})
.controller('TabsCtrl', function TabCtrl(TabService) { 
    this.tabs = TabService.tabs; /* to make it bindable in view */
    this.openTab = TabService.openTab; /* to attach to some ng-click or whatever */
})
```

Looks strange, but is there another way?

## 3

When new tab is created it should be passed some parameters from TabService.openTab method. Or, it may request the parameters from TabService if it could identify itself.

If creating tabs with

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in ctrl.tabs"><ng-include src="tab.src"></tab>
```

With tab.src referencing to some partial html with attached controllers inside, how could such controller communicate with outer scope?

Answer (score 0):

ui-router can be configured with controller and empty template

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: "/foo/index",
      template: 'empty',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
    .state('foo', {
      url: "/foo/:fooId",
      template: 'empty',
      controller: 'FooCtrl'
      });
```

This controller is called every time state changes and passed state parameters.
It can then access service to switch/open/create tabs.

Another controller needed to bind service with view.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ns344fo9u4C1nbQ77Jd8

And ng-repeat rerenders only when object identity changes.